# jQuery Dialog hover thumbnails using ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a little problem in making a small functionnality using jQuery and ASP.NET MVC 4.

I have a list of thumbnails, wich represents a list of products in my aplication :

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
                @foreach (var thumbnail in Model.ForfaitsInThumbNail)
                {
            <!-- Now I Display Some infos about the thumbnail -->
            <!-- This is the Dialog that I want to display when the cursor is hover every thumbnail -->
            <div class='pop-up' id='pop-up'><h3>"@thumbnail.Forfait.Titre"</h3><p>"@thumbnail.Forfait.Description"</p></div>
                    </div>
            <!-- This simply displays a description and the title of every product -->
                }
</ul>
```

Well, I have a jQuery function that displays the pop-up menu customized to display the specific title and description of every product :

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $('.thumbnail').hover(function (e) {
        $('#pop-up').show()
            .css('top', e.pageY + 20)
            .css('left', e.pageX + 10)
            .appendTo('body');
    }, function () {
        $('#pop-up').hide();
    });
    $('.thumbnail').mousemove(function (e) {
        $("#pop-up").css('top', e.pageY + 20).css('left', e.pageX + 10);
    });
</script>
```

So this function is working well, but it is not satisfying all my needs, because it only displays the title and description of the last thumbnail, but I need a function that narrows every div that have **'thumbnail'** and displays it's specefic title and description. Any Ideas ? I would be very thankful for your help :)

**Edit**

Here is my new function like suggested :

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
    $('.pointHere').hover(function (e) {
        $(this).children('.pop-up').show()
            .css('top', e.pageY + 20)
            .css('left', e.pageX + 10)
            .appendTo('body');
    }, function () {
        $(this).children('.pop-up').hide();
    });
    $('.pointHere').mousemove(function (e) {
        $(this).children('.pop-up').css('top', e.pageY + 20).css('left', e.pageX + 10);
    });
</script>
```

I made a div wich has a class pointHere, and when we click to it the child element pop-up is displayed :) that works fine :) but the mouseover function doesn't work, also the hover function doesn't hide the pop-up when the mouse is not hover the pointHere div.

Comment: Maybe you can provide compiled HTML instead of mix of ASP.NET and HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the id `pop-up`. It is not unique. You have the same Id for all of your thumbnails

Instead of binding `hover` on `.thumbnail`, bind it on `.pop-up` and use `this` to get hold of that div

```
$('.pop-up').hover(function (e) {
    $(this).show()
        .css('top', e.pageY + 20)
        .css('left', e.pageX + 10)
        .appendTo('body');
}, function () {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Also, you have bad HTML. Your pop-up div is closed twice.

Comment: your idea is great :) but the thing is that the pop-up div is set to hidden by default (in the css), now when i run this, there is no specefic place where the user can point to show the pop-up, because it is hidden.

Comment: I made an edit, the displaying workd fine, but when the mouse is not hover the div, the child div, doesn't hide, also the mouseover function is not working, but the previous problems where solved :)